# OpenZeppelin onlyOwner modifier doesn't work properly

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

In the Remix, getICOMembers function works appropriately and returns all members of a specific ICO type after they are added to the icoMembers mapping.

```
mapping(uint256 => address[]) private icoMembers;
```

```
function getICOMembers(uint256 _icoType) external view onlyOwner returns (address[] memory) 
{
    return icoMembers[_icoType];
}
```

[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFMfo.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7sZZ.png)

But Etherscan gives this error even if I connected by owner address.

[deployer address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft7bZ.png) [owner address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZqVI.png) [etherscan error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOSAa.png)

Also, this function has onlyOwner modifier too but it works.

```
ICOdata[] private ICOdatas;
```

```
function getICODatas() external view onlyOwner returns (ICOdata[] memory) 
{
    return ICOdatas; 
}
```

[getICODatas function output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEbRo.png)

I tried to add members by hardcoding instead of joining the token sale function, changing external to public but it still gives the same error.

Also, this is the constructor.

```
constructor(
    address _token,
    address payable _usdtWallet,
    address _vestingContract
) {
    require(
        address(_token) != address(0),
        "ERROR at Crowdsale constructor: Token contract address shouldn't be zero address."
    );
    require(
        _usdtWallet != address(0),
        "ERROR at Crowdsale constructor: USDT wallet address shouldn't be zero address."
    );
    require(
        _vestingContract != address(0),
        "ERROR at Crowdsale constructor: Vesting contract address shouldn't be zero address."
    );

    token = ERC20(_token);
    usdtWallet = _usdtWallet;
    totalAllocation = 0;
    vestingContract = IVesting(_vestingContract);
    transferOwnership(msg.sender);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a constructor that specifies msg.sender is owner? Show more code so it will be easier to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Constructor added.

Answer (score 0):

A `view` function is usually invoked using a read-only [call](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_call) - not using a [transaction](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendtransaction).

Unlike transaction, a call is not signed by any private key. So you can specify any `from` address that is reflected as the value of `msg.sender`.

Then it depends on the specific implementation of the UI and of the node that processes the call. My guess is that Remix IDE uses the currently selected address from the accounts list as `msg.sender` (which passes the `onlyOwner` validation), while Etherscan uses the [zero address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) (which fails the validation).

Comment: But both functions use onlyOwner and only getICODatas onlyOwner modifier works as it's supposed to whereas as you said view functions have no msg.sender. What is the problem that makes it work in one and not the other?

Comment: @sametmollaoglu I'm not able to reproduce it exactly, so I'm not sure, and only guessing that there might be some cached value on Etherscan's side that bypasses the validation altogether... But generally, it's not advisable to rely on `onlyOwner` with the (read-only) calls. It works fine with transactions.